# How do I battle another Trainer in the Great League?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the Special Research section in Pokemon Go, I need to "Battle  Another Trainer in the Great League".

So I go to "Pokemon>Party>Great League>Create Team & Select My Pokemon>?" but what happens after I select my pokemon? They are just kind of there in a blue box...How do I battle?

Answer (score 8):

In the context of what you just did, you created a “party”. These are pre-made teams for battles.

As far as battles, there are two ways to initiate this

**Close Range**

This can be done with any trainer in close proximity. To battle another trainer, click the “Near By” bar on the bottom right of your screen and the swipe left. In this menu, there will be one of two options:

- To send a battle request, click “Challenge Trainer”. This will open your camera to scan the QR code of the opposing trainer
- To receive a battle request, click the box with the QR code for the opposing trainer to scan

**Long Range**

By going to your friends list and viewing a trainer profile, you have the ability to challenge anybody whom you are Ultra or Best Friends from anywhere in the world. In the trainer profile, press “Battle” to send a battle request

After doing either of the above and both trainers are ready, you can now partake in a trainer battle